# Swift - Function acts differently depending on where is it called

Tags: swift, function, swift2

In swift, if I called the function levelCompleted() in the viewDidLoad() function it would work as expected. However if I call the function anywhere else, the result of the function is a mess of blocks which should be in an order.

Here is the code which is being used.

```
//
//  ACLevelScene.swift
//  Stick Exscape
//
//  Created by Austin Collins on 24/08/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Austin Collins. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class ACLevelScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var player: ACPlayer!
    let grid: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
    var doorIsOpen = false
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        // Change scenes anchor point
        self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake (0.5,0.5);

        // Allow multiable touches
        view.multipleTouchEnabled = true

        // Show physics for debug
        //view.showsPhysics = true

        // Background Color
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 46/255, green: 32/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)

        // Draw the grid
        drawGrid()

        // Level to load
        loadLevel(2)

        // Add the notice
        addChild(notice)

        // When called here it works ax expected
        //levelCompleted()

    }

    func levelCompleted() {
        print("Open the menu because level is finished")
        print("We also need to save that this level has been completed and in what time.")
        print("This can also remove all the grids childs and load the next level.")
        grid.removeAllChildren()
        loadLevel(1)
    }

    func loadLevel(level: Float) {

        doorIsOpen = false

        var x: Int = 0
        var y: Int = 0
        let levelNumber: Int = Int(level)
        let blocks = storedLevels[levelNumber]

        let levelGridWidth = storedLevelSettings[levelNumber]?["gridWidth"]
        let gridWidth: CGFloat = CGFloat(levelGridWidth!)
        let levelGridHeight = storedLevelSettings[levelNumber]?["gridHeight"]
        let gridHeight: CGFloat = CGFloat(levelGridHeight!)

        grid.size.width = gridWidth*gBlockWidth
        grid.size.height = gridHeight*gBlockHeight

        // Set color here so levels can define a custom background in the future
        grid.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let backgroundImage = SKTexture(imageNamed: "sky.png")
        grid.texture = backgroundImage

        for var i: CGFloat = 0; i <= (gridHeight - 1); i += 1 {
            y = Int(i)
            for var i: CGFloat = 0; i <= (gridWidth-1); i += 1 {
                x = Int(i)

                let blockNumber = (gridWidth * CGFloat(y)) + CGFloat(x)

                if let block = blocks?[Int(blockNumber)] {
                    addBlockToGrid(CGFloat(block), x: CGFloat(x), y: CGFloat(y), gridHeight: gridHeight)
                } else {
                    addBlockToGrid(0, x: CGFloat(x), y: CGFloat(y), gridHeight: gridHeight)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func addPlayer(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
        player = ACPlayer()
        player.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
        player.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
        player.zPosition = 5
        grid.addChild(player)
    }

    func drawGrid() {

        grid.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1)
        grid.position = CGPointMake(-(grid.size.width/2), -(grid.size.height/2))
        addChild(grid)
        let expand = SKAction.scaleXTo(0.8, y: 0.8, duration: 0)
        grid.runAction(expand)

    }

    func addBlockToGrid(blockType: CGFloat, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, gridHeight: CGFloat) {

        let xPosition: CGFloat = (x*gBlockWidth) + gBlockWidth/2
        let yPosition: CGFloat = (gridHeight - (gBlockHeight*y)) - gBlockWidth/2
        var block: SKSpriteNode!
        var blockTexture: SKTexture!

        if blockType == 0 {
            // Air block
            // Do nothing
        }
        else if blockType == 1 {

            // Dirt Block
            blockTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "dirtBlock.png")
            block = SKSpriteNode(texture: blockTexture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: gBlockSize)
            block.position.x = xPosition
            block.position.y = yPosition
            block.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)

            block.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: gBlockSize)
            block.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
            block.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

            grid.addChild(block)

        }
        else if blockType == 2 {

            // Grass Block
            blockTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "grassBlock.png")
            block = SKSpriteNode(texture: blockTexture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: gBlockSize)
            block.position.x = xPosition
            block.position.y = yPosition
            block.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)

            block.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: gBlockSize)
            block.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            block.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

            grid.addChild(block)

        }
        else if blockType == 3 {

            // Ice Block
            blockTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "iceBlock.png")
            block = SKSpriteNode(texture: blockTexture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: gBlockSize)
            block.position.x = xPosition
            block.position.y = yPosition
            block.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)

            block.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: gBlockSize)
            block.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            block.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

            grid.addChild(block)

        }
        else if blockType == 4 {

            // Stone Block
            blockTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "stoneBlock.png")
            block = SKSpriteNode(texture: blockTexture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: gBlockSize)
            block.position.x = xPosition
            block.position.y = yPosition
            block.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)

            block.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: gBlockSize)
            block.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            block.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

            grid.addChild(block)

        }
        else if blockType == 5 {

            // Flower Block
            blockTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "flowerBlock.png")
            block = SKSpriteNode(texture: blockTexture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: gBlockSize)
            block.position.x = xPosition
            block.position.y = yPosition
            block.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)

            grid.addChild(block)


        }
        else if blockType == 6 {

            addPlayer(xPosition, y: yPosition)

        }
        else if blockType == 7.0 {

            // Bottom Of Door
            blockTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "doorBottomBlock.png")
            block = SKSpriteNode(texture: blockTexture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: gBlockSize)
            block.position.x = xPosition
            block.position.y = yPosition
            block.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
            block.name = "doorBottom"

            block.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: gBlockSize)
            block.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            block.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            block.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = doorCategory
            block.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory
            block.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1

            grid.addChild(block)

        }
        else if blockType == 7.1 {

            // Top Of Door
            blockTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "doorTopBlock.png")
            block = SKSpriteNode(texture: blockTexture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: gBlockSize)
            block.position.x = xPosition
            block.position.y = yPosition
            block.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
            block.name = "doorTop"


            block.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: gBlockSize)
            block.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            block.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            block.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = doorCategory
            block.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory
            block.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1

            grid.addChild(block)

        }
        else if blockType == 8 {

            // Key
            blockTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "keyBlock.png")
            let keySize = CGSizeMake(gBlockWidth/2, gBlockHeight/2)
            block = SKSpriteNode(texture: blockTexture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: keySize)
            block.position.x = xPosition
            block.position.y = yPosition
            block.name = "key"
            block.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)

            block.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: keySize)
            block.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
            block.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
            block.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = keyCategory
            block.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory


            let keyBounce = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 3), duration: 1)
            let keyPutBack = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -3), duration: 1)
            let keyBounceSequence = SKAction.sequence([keyBounce, keyPutBack])
            block.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(keyBounceSequence))

            grid.addChild(block)

        }
        else if blockType == 9 {

            // Barrier
            block = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: gBlockSize)
            block.position.x = xPosition
            block.position.y = yPosition
            block.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)

            block.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: gBlockSize)
            block.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            block.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

            grid.addChild(block)

        }

    }

    func centerOnNode(node: SKNode) {
        let nodePosition: CGPoint = convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: grid)
        grid.position = CGPointMake(grid.position.x - nodePosition.x,
            grid.position.y - nodePosition.y - gBlockHeight)
    }

    // Outside to avoid updates
    var isZoomedOut = false


    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        let bodyOne: SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
        let bodyTwo: SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB
        if (bodyOne.categoryBitMask == playerCategory && bodyTwo.categoryBitMask == keyCategory) || (bodyOne.categoryBitMask == keyCategory && bodyTwo.categoryBitMask == playerCategory) {
            let key = grid.childNodeWithName("key")
            key!.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            let keyAnimation = SKAction.rotateByAngle(720, duration: 0.3)
            key?.runAction(keyAnimation, completion: { () -> Void in
                key?.removeFromParent()
                self.player.hasKey(true)
                self.sendNotice("You got the key!")
                let doorBottomTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "doorBottomOpenBlock.png")
                let doorTopTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "doorTopOpenBlock.png")
                let doorBottom: SKSpriteNode = self.grid.childNodeWithName("doorBottom") as! SKSpriteNode
                let doorTop: SKSpriteNode = self.grid.childNodeWithName("doorTop") as! SKSpriteNode
                doorBottom.texture = doorBottomTexture
                doorTop.texture = doorTopTexture
                self.doorIsOpen = true
            })
        }
        if (bodyOne.categoryBitMask == playerCategory && bodyTwo.categoryBitMask == doorCategory) || (bodyOne.categoryBitMask == doorCategory && bodyTwo.categoryBitMask == playerCategory) {
            if doorIsOpen {
                self.sendNotice("Level Completed!")

                // It does not work when called from here
                self.levelCompleted()
            } else {
                self.sendNotice("The door is locked.")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have removed all of the code that is not used in any of the function that are relevant.

I was wondering if there is anything different happening depending on where or when it is being called.

I have also tried putting the function on a timer in the viewDidLoad() function, calling the function in the normal way. Even like this, when called in the collision method it does not work the same, and when the timer runs out it works as normal.

Comment: iterating over `CGFloat` is pretty dangeours. The `<=` condition won't work as you expect. Regarding your problem, it should be pretty easy to find the difference. Put `print` for every variable there and run the function from those two places. Then compare differences, you should find the difference then.

Comment: @Sulthan I have tried, I still can't seem to find the issue. I don't know why the result is different depending on where you call it.